# Cordinate between my repository classes and controller classes to be using the same Context object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. now i have created multiple repositories classes, for example i have the following abstract repository classes:-

```
public interface ISkillRepository : IDisposable
{//code goes here..
```

&

```
public interface IStaffRepository : IDisposable
{//code goes here
```

and the model Repositories:-

```
public class SkillRepository :  ISkillRepository , IDisposable
                {
 private SkillManagementEntities context = new SkillManagementEntities();
    //code goes here
```

&

```
public class StaffRepository :  IStaffRepository , IDisposable
                {
                    private SkillManagementEntities context = new SkillManagementEntities();
```

now inside y controller i am intializing and creating the repo as follow:-

```
 public class SkillController : Controller
    {

        private ISkillRepository skillRepository;


      public SkillController() : this(new SkillRepository()) {}

      public SkillController(ISkillRepository repository)
      {
          skillRepository = repository;
      }
```

but currently i got the following error inside my application:

```
The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
```

and the problem is that i need to be passing the same context accross the repos and controllers. so can anyone adivce on this:-

1. how i can inside one model repo to reference another repo using the same context class. for example inside the Staff repositoryto referecne the skill repository?
2. how i can inside a controller class to refer multiple repos , but at the same time pass the same context object among them , so if i issue a save() it will wrap all the statements inside one transaction. for example insie my skillController to reference both the skill & staff repos using the same context object ?

Thanks

**Edit**
I have created the following Unit of work class:-

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private SkillManagementEntities context = new SkillManagementEntities();
        private SkillRepository skillRepository;
        private StaffRepository staffRepository;
        private SecurityRoleRepository securityroleRepository;
        public SkillRepository SkillRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.skillRepository == null)
                {
                    this.skillRepository = new SkillRepository(context);
                }
                return skillRepository;
            }
        }

        public StaffRepository StaffRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.staffRepository == null)
                {
                    this.staffRepository = new StaffRepository(context);
                }
                return staffRepository;
            }
        }
        public SecurityRoleRepository SecurityRoleRepository
        {
            get
            {

                if (this.staffRepository == null)
                {
                    this.staffRepository = new SecurityRoleRepository(context);
                }
                return securityroleRepository;
            }
        }
        public async Task Save()
        {
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and then inside my repo i did the following:-

```
 public class SecurityRoleRepository :  ISecurityRoleRepository , IDisposable
        {
            private SkillManagementEntities context;// = new SkillManagementEntities();

            public SecurityRoleRepository(SkillManagementEntities context)
            {
              this.context = context;
```

and on the controller class i will be referencing the UnitOfWork as follow:-

```
   public class SecurityRoleController : Controller
    {

        private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string filter = null, int page = 1, int pageSize = 20, string sort = "Name", string sortdir = "ASC")
        {

            try
            {
                var records = new PagedList<SecurityRole>();
                ViewBag.filter = filter;
                records.Content = await unitOfWork.SecurityRoleRepository.GetSecurityRoleForGrid(filter, page, pageSize, sort, sortdir).ToListAsync();
```

now i am facing a problem is that how i can referecne a repo from another Repo ? for example how i can reference the Skill repo inside the SecurityRole repo ?

**EDIT Final**
i did the following steps:-
1. i install

```
Install-Package Ninject.MVC5
```

2. then i created the following dependency class:-

```
    public class YourDependencyResolverClass : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public YourDependencyResolverClass()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }


    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<ISkillRepository>().To<SkillRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IStaffRepository>().To<StaffRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISecurityRoleRepository>().To<SecurityRoleRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISkillVersionHistoryRepository>().To<SkillVersionHistoryRepository>();
     }
}
}
```

3.now inside my SkillRepository class i will be referencing the StaffRepository as follow:-

```
   public class SkillRepository :  ISkillRepository , IDisposable
            {
                private SkillManagementEntities context ;

                private IStaffRepository staffrepo = (IStaffRepository)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IStaffRepository));
                public SkillRepository(SkillManagementEntities context)
                {
                  this.context = context;
                }
```

Finally inside my action method i will be calling the Uiteofwork class as follow:-

```
 public class StaffController : Controller
    {
        //private SkillManagementEntities db = new SkillManagementEntities();

        UnitOfWork unitofwork = new UnitOfWork();




    public async Task<ActionResult> AutoComplete(string term)
      {

          var staff = await unitofwork.StaffRepository.GetAllActiveStaff(term).Select(a => new { label = a.SamAccUserName }).ToListAsync();

          return Json(staff, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and the unite of work class is :-

```
   public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
        {
            private SkillManagementEntities context = new SkillManagementEntities();
            private SkillRepository skillRepository;
            private StaffRepository staffRepository;
            private SecurityRoleRepository securityroleRepository;
            private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
            private SkillVersionHistoryRepository SVH;
            public SkillRepository SkillRepository
            {
                get
                {

                    if (this.skillRepository == null)
                    {
                        this.skillRepository = new SkillRepository(context);
                    }
                    return skillRepository;
                }
            }

            public StaffRepository StaffRepository
            {
                get
                {

                    if (this.staffRepository == null)
                    {
                        this.staffRepository = new StaffRepository(context);
                    }
                    return staffRepository;
                }
            }
            public CustomerRepository CustomerRepository
            {
                get
                {

                    if (this.customerRepository == null)
                    {
                        this.customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(context);
                    }
                    return customerRepository;
                }
            }
            public SecurityRoleRepository SecurityRoleRepository
            {
                get
                {

                    if (this.securityroleRepository == null)
                    {
                        this.securityroleRepository = new SecurityRoleRepository(context);
                    }
                    return securityroleRepository;
                }
            }
            public SkillVersionHistoryRepository SkillVersionHistoryRepository 
            {
                get
                {

                    if (this.SVH == null)
                    {
                        this.SVH = new SkillVersionHistoryRepository(context);
                    }
                    return SVH;
                }
            }
            public async Task Save()
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            private bool disposed = false;

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!this.disposed)
                {
                    if (disposing)
                    {
                        context.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
```

So can you adivce if my approach of using unitefwork and DI will guarantee that all my statements will be warped inside a single DB transaction ? thnaks?

Comment: Look into dependency injection. Any good DI container should let you bind a type to an instance for the life of the request. I personally use Ninject, and have found it to be very easy to use. However, there's many options; find the one that works best for you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for the reply, but could i use something such as http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application in my case?

Comment: Not sure where is a problem with in this completely new question - you create objects in one localized place - clearly you should be able to pass references to constructors as needed... Or `Func<ISomeInterface>` if you have circular dependencies... (I'd still claim that DI frameworks are way more convenient way to resolve/inject dependencies - but doing it by hand not too hard for each particular case either).

Comment: but how i can reference for example the StaffRepository inside the SecurityRoleRepository to be able to use its methods ? i mean if i write something such as "private StaffRepository s = new StaffRepository();;" inside the SecurityroleRepository i will get an error that " 'SkillManagement.DAL.StaffRepository' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" .. so how i will be passing the same context to the StaffRepo constructor inside the SecurityRole repo ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can you adivce please on my above comment ?

Comment: how about:

 var s = new StaffRepository(this.context)?

I'd like to note, however, that it seems you're jumping through a lot of hoops to avoid an already existing solution to your problem: a dependency injection scheme that handles context scoped objects.

Comment: @johnG I'm still lost on what the problem is, sorry. Your post shows passing dependencies to constructors as well as `this.StaffRepository` - I assume  you have no the problem to pass `this.StaffRepository` to `SecurityRoleRepository` constructor, so what you have problem with?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i am not sure if i am doing things correclty ,, can you please check my "EDIT Final" section ?

Answer (score 2):

We handle this by sharing a context using a singleton that is scoped to the request using HttpContext:

```
    public MyContext GetContext()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["MyScopedContext"] == null)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["MyScopedContext"] = new MyContext();
        }

        return (MyContext)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["MyScopedContext"];
    }
```

The context object (repository) itself essentially houses a Unit of Work. The code I  added above just gives you a way to share a single repository across all code running within a request. If your repository classes are defined in the scope of a web application, you can just replace your direct instantiation of SkillManagementEntities() with a call to a GetContext() method.

On the other hand if your repositories are defined in a layer shared by heterogeneous applications, you may need to get your context from a factory object that you can inject as needed. Either way, creating a new context object per repository is what's causing your issue.

Comment: ca you adivce more on this ? is it the same as using Unit of work?

Comment: I edited my above answer to explain in a little more detail. Hopefully will get you on the right track.

Comment: i am unable to understand where i need to define "public MyContext GetContext()" inside my application ???

Comment: You'd access it from a static object, typically injected on app startup. I started to write a boatload of code that made a lot of assumptions about your environment, but then I decided to do some searching for you:

Have you, by chance, stumbled across this yet?

http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122

I think it gives more good options than I am able to in this space.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer**: this "use DI" suggestion answers a bit different question - OP is looking for "unit-of-work" pattern - while basic case (lifetime of unit of work matches lifetime of request/controller) can easily be solved with any DI framework, managing multiple units of work or units of work with longer lifetime is much harder and dedicated "unit of work factory" ([sample usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx#id0420021)) is likely the solution.

---

Usually when you go that far with interfaces/repositories and constructor dependency injection you have some Dependency Injection framework. There is a good chance that one you are using already provides "per HTTP request" resolution or allows to easily add one.

I.e. if you using Unity there is `PerRequestLifetime` lifetime manager that makes all `.Resolve` calls for the same interface/object to return the same instance for given request. See more info in [DI with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec18) MSDN article.

Approximate sample:

```
container.RegisterType<ISkillRepository, SkillRepository>();
container.RegisterType<IOtherRepository, OtherRepository>();
container.RegisterType<TheContext, TheContext>(new PerRequestLifetime());
```

With such registration and assuming you've configured ASP.Net MVC to use Unity to resolve types when controller is created it will get necessary dependencies (new instances as registered with default lifetime), but both will share the same context (assuming each depends on `TheContext` class either via constructor or property injection).

Comment: thanks for the reply,, i am not using Unity ,, i was looking for something such as http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application but on the example they use generic repo ,, while in my case i do not ,, so i got confused on how i can implement this unit of work class inside my application ?

Comment: @johnG - I see - edited my post to clarify that this is not an approach you are looking for (keeping non-deleted so others don't suggest the same route you don't want)

Comment: thanks for the update , but i am a bit confused on how i can implement this in my case,, currently i have separate context objects inside each repository,, and i am assign the interface to my controller class, so i need to be able to pass the same context object between the different repos inside my controller, and also if i am referencing a repo inside another repo to be able to reference the same context object